# How can I make my status bar background white with Tailwind in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, statusbar

I'm working on a website, build with reactjs and tailwindcss, and now I'm trying to make it look good on my iPhone (Safari). But I can't seem to make the statusbar/background white.

[image: Black statusbar]

[image: Black statusbar]

I've tried adding meta tags with react helmet but that doesn't do anything:

```
<Helmet>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">`
</Helmet>
```

And I've tried this:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) 0 0 0;
}
```

But neither does anything to make the statusbar white... I can't seem to find any other approach, but so many websites have white statusbars on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I didn't use React Helmet, or write css to solve it.

In your  section of your index.html file, use the same properties as you did in your code and you should be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34494010)